# Woocommerce get the transaction details when placing the order?

Tags: woocommerce

How we can get the transaction details when placing the order in woocommerce, to use that details for some custom database or send that details to other server ?
I have used the woocommerce hook `woocommerce_new_order` but it only print the order details. Is any other hook to get the complete traction details ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have order id you can simply get the transaction id by doing this:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id();
...
```

Check out [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1034-1041) to get more useful info.